# How to populate option tag after ajax response?

Tags: ajax, json

I have a form with 2 select box and a hidden field. First select box is main category, second select box is sub category. When a value in first select box is chosen, values from second select box will be drawn from database and display accordingly.

I used onchange function on first select box to trigger ajax call and its response will be values from database. However, this values are not populated in html file. How can I populate these values in the second select box after ajax response? Because when these option value are populated, I can use it to trigger something else. However, I am stucked at this stage, Please help!

Here is my form:

```
 <form>
 <select id='main-cat' name='maincat' onchange="sortSubcat(this.value)"/>
  <option value="">Please select one category</option>
  <option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
 </select>

 <div id='subcat-more'>
  <select id='subcat' name='subcat'>
    <option value=''>Please select a subcategory</option>
  </select>   
 </div>

<div id='morefield' style='display:none'>
   <input type='text' name='option1'/>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is ajax function:

```
function sortSubcat(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
 document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML="";
 return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/member/sortsubcat.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
require_once("../configs/dbconnect.php");
if (!empty($_GET['q'])){
$q = basename($_GET['q']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE maincat=:q";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':q', $q);
$result->execute();
echo "<option value=''>Please select a sub cat</option>";
foreach($result as $row)
{
echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";
}
}
else{
echo "<option value=''>Please select a subcat</option>";
}
$conn=null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to say without having your development environment setup on my computer. Any errors in the javascript console? Have you checked to see if it makes it to your `document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`? Just taking a look at the code, it seems correct.

I'd recommend using jQuery because it has better browser compatibility and a more elegant way to accomplish your task.

You'll of course need this somewhere in your HTML file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And your sortSubCat() method might look a little something like this (*untested*)

```
function sortSubcat(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    $("#subcat").html("");
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/member/sortsubcat.php",
    data: "q=" + str,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#subcat").html(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, error) {
      alert("Status: " + status);
      alert("Error: " + error); 
    }
  })
}
```

If you can't use jQuery, the questions I asked above might help a bit.